# How will running two displays (same image) affect performance

Tags: display, performance, chipset

I want to run the same image on two screens. The colour should be the same and so should the red, but one is a slightly bigger screen. Would this affect the performance of the PC?

I have a GeForce GTX 970. if I wanted to use two screens am I better of using the graphics card as my main monitor (the graphics card as 4 HDMI  ports) and then using the port on the motherboard as the secondary card?

My thinking is that the motherboard internal graphics chip will not be used wile the pci express is taking over so if I plug it into the motherboard will it use the dormant chip to display the image and would that mean it will not take any work from the graphics card

I'm thinking about using hdmi for both screens my mother bored has an hdmi output it's also a gigabyte motherboard.

I want to use my office monitor purely for work related stuff and then my other monitor which is more comfortable place to play games as my gaming monitor so I don't need to run two windows just the one desktop.

So my question is should I plug both monitors into the graphics card hdmi both will display same image.

Or should I plug one into the graphics card and one into the motherboard?

Comment: I wanted to add that when one monitor is on the other will be off I want to do two different things but I only need one display so it will be a mirror thanks for the arnswer just one more question would it make a difference if the resolution is different in case I decide to change them later I don't think I'll need to but if I did can you mirror with two monitors at different resolutions bearing in mind only one monitor will be on at a time thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You should plug both monitors into the graphics card, as your graphics card is substantially more powerful than the built-in GPU.

If they are displaying the same image, this takes almost no additional processing power. It's not remotely clear this is your intention, though, as you say you want to use the monitors for different things. If you aren't mirroring your display, this will take additional processing power on the graphics card. Probably not enough to notice, unless you are doing 3D graphics (for example, games) across both displays.